# Is there any way to use NativeCSS in Xamarin.Forms using Visual Studio?

Tags: xamarin

I am working on Xamarin.Forms in visual studio for corss platform application,
i heard about NativeCSS, here is the [website](https://nativecss.com/documentation/get-started/getting-started-with-xamarin/).
My question is how do i use NativeCSS in my application using xamarin.forms, is it possible to us it in xamarin.forms ??
And my other question is that is someone tell me about the architecture of NativeCSS .. how it is work i mean at run this css is converted into c# or any other language ??

Comment: They already provide an example/tutorial using Forms https://nativecss.com/blog/2015/06/simple-cross-platform-styling-for-xamarin-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Its is for Xamarin Studio not for visual studio..